# Best way to declare ALL constant variable in APPLICATION

Tags: c#, wpf, constants

What are the best ways to declare a constant  variable ?

OR

How can i pass the value of all constant variables in the application ?

User Case:  I want to be able to change the logo, title or file name( e.g. in appData Directory).

Fact: I am providing user interface to different clients and each client should get a unique name of each using constant/s  variable in software.

Comment: Did you forget to include **tag** in your question.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear and unreadable, but are you looking for a resource assembly?

Answer (score 0):

your question is very unclear, but it looks like what you are asking is how to create sudo constants i.e a value that is constant as far as the running code is concerned but can be tweaked to produce different behaviour, if so then this is exactly what Resources and settings are for

[Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx) store data that your application uses but they can be in a separate file to the main exe, which means that you can just pop in a new resource file and change the resources your code is using for example if you have all your text in a resource file then you can just toss in a resource file with French text and next time your app runs it will be in French, there is even a mechanism to do that automatically base on culture

[Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) are a little different as they aren't designed for storing large complex values, they store smaller simpler data in a hierarchy, the lowest level is system settings that you should never use, next is application settings and finally user settings, the way it works is that when the application runs it looks for the highest level setting that exists then gets the setting from that file, this means that every user can have slightly different settings that can be customised at run time, so the first time a user runs the system they get the default settings, then they customise them and save them in their user config file, then the next time their settings will be loaded with out affecting anyone else